# Why is PropTypes throwing error in an internal function of a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-props, react-component

I have defined a stateless functional component as such:

```js
// a is a list of object, each having 'title' & 'subtitle' property
export const SampleComponent = ({a}) => {
    const internalFunction = ({ title, subtitle}) => {
        // return a jsx based on title and subtitle
        return;
    };
    return a && a.length && <div className='sampleComponent'>
        { a.map(item => internalFunction(item) }
    </div>
};

SampleComponent.propTypes = {
    a: PropTypes.object
};
```

But when I run eslint on the file it throws me an error like this:

```
error  'title' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
error  'subtitle' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
```

The line number these error point is where I have defined `internalFunction`. 
But I am unable to figure out why I am getting this error because the `title` & `subtitle` are not part of `props` to my `SampleComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding proptypes to internal component as well.

```
const internalFunction = ({ title, subtitle}) => {
    // return a jsx based on title and subtitle
    return;
};
internalFunction.propTypes = {
   title: PropTypes.string,
   subtitle: PropTypes.string
};
return a && a.length && <div className='sampleComponent'>
    { a.map(item => internalFunction(item) }
</div>
```

Comment: But why is it required for the `internalFunction`? It's not a component which requires its own props to be defined

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing an array in the props, the proper way to write `propType` would be

```
SampleComponent.propTypes = {
    a: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        title: PropTypes.string,
        subtitle: PropTypes.string
      }))
};
```

That should resolve the eslint errors.